# Is it necessary to create primary and foreign keys in order to use tpc-h benchmark?

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation, benchmark

I'm doing some tests with tpc-h benchmark. The tpch-h benchmark simulates a data warehouse environment. The most important things here are the queries against the data warehouse. Therefore, does it make sense to create primary and foreign keys for this benchmark? I read some articles that do that, but I don't understand why it's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification TPC BENCHMARKTM H, Standard Specification, Revision 2.17.1, can be found [here](http://www.tpc.org/TPC_Documents_Current_Versions/pdf/TPC-H_v2.17.1.pdf). See section "1. LOGICAL DATABASE DESIGN / 1.5 IMPLEMENTATION RULES". Indexes can be created on combinations of  fields defined in 1.4.2.2 and 1.4.2.3 and on date fields. Indexes may only contain fields of one table. So indexes can be built on the following fields:

- Table PART:

  - P_PARTKEY
- Table SUPPLIER:

  - S_SUPPKEY
- Table PARTSUPP:

  - PS_PARTKEY
  - PS_SUPPKEY
- Table CUSTOMER:

  - C_CUSTKEY
  - C_NATIONKEY
- Table ORDERS:

  - O_ORDERKEY
  - O_CUSTKEY
  - O_ORDERDATE
- Table REGION:

  - R_REGIONKEY
- Table LINEITEM:

  - L_LINENUMBER
  - L_ORDERKEY
  - L_PARTKEY
  - L_SUPPKEY
  - L_SHIPDATE
  - L_COMMITDATE
  - L_RECEIPTDATE
- Table NATION:

  - N_NATIONKEY
  - N_REGIONKEY

Comment: Reading this answer I want to give +1 for going into the trouble of searching **and finding** the official docs about these benchmarks. And at the same time a -1 for copying a rather irrelevant part about **indexes** while the question is about **primary and foreign keys**.